# Cannot invoke 'addAnimations' with an argument list of type '(() -> (), delayFactor: Double)'

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewpropertyanimator

I'm using `UIViewPropertyAnimator` to control the progress of multiple animations. I have a 2d array of UIView subclasses. I want to display all elements at each index at once. For some reason the compiler won't let me add new animations with a delay by using `addAnimations(_:delayFactor:)` method. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

```
// I'm creating a new viewAnimator without any animations. No problems here
        self.viewAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: self.frameDelay * Double(self.spillBubbles.count),
                                                   curve: .easeIn,
                                                   animations: {})


        for (index, views) in self.spillBubbles.enumerated() {

            views.forEach({ self.simulationView.addSubview($0) })

            // That's where the compiler error occurs 
            self.viewAnimator!.addAnimations({
                views.forEach({ self.simulationView.addSubview($0) })
            }, delayFactor: Double(index) / Double(self.spillBubbles.count))

        }
```

When I try to call .addAnimations I get the following message: 
`Cannot invoke 'addAnimations' with an argument list of type '(() -> (), delayFactor: Double)'`

What am I doing wrong here? The same closure called in the `UIViewPropertyAnimator` initializers works without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. Just look at the docs if it isn't clear enough:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator/1648370-addanimations

The `delayFactor` needs to be a CGFloat, not a Double.

Comment: Note too that the `delayFactor` is a percentage, not a time.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question. For my defense I was kind tired yesterday. Now the message is completely clear.